# How to reference static IP address in ARM template?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I have public static IP address with name **'VPNPublicIP'** in resource group. How to reference this  address in below ARM template ? I don't want to this static to change

```
 "resources": [
{
      "apiVersion": "[variables('apiVersion')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
      "name": "[variables('WebPublicIPName')]",
      "location": "[variables('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Static",
        "publicIPAddress": "VPNPublicIP",

      }
    }
}
```

I believe the one above is not correct, please advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference the existing public IP to another resource with its resource Id:

```
"publicIPAddress": {
       "id":"[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses',variables('publicIPAddressName'))]"
 },
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to reference it in the same resource, you just need to set its `privateIPAllocationMethod` property to static and thats it. it will be created as a static ip address.

```
{
    "apiVersion": "[variables('apiVersion')]",
    "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
    "name": "[variables('WebPublicIPName')]",
    "location": "[variables('location')]",
    "properties": {
        "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Static"
    }
}
```

if you want to attach it to something you can use the `resourceId()` function as the other answer suggests.